# php sum of amount in array if 2 values exist

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not sure how to formulate the title of my question.
I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [account] => 700000
            [percent] => 0.0000
            [amount] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [account] => 705010
            [percent] => 6.0000
            [amount] => 4.7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [account] => 700000
            [percent] => 0.0000
            [amount] => 93
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [account] => 700000
            [percent] => 6.0000
            [amount] => 9.43
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [account] => 700000
            [percent] => 12.0000
            [amount] => 35.72
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [account] => 700000
            [percent] => 21.0000
            [amount] => 8.26
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [account] => 705300
            [percent] => 21.0000
            [amount] => 8.26
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [account] => 705300
            [percent] => 21.0000
            [amount] => 57.86
        )

)
```

I need to find a way to add up the amount if both account and percent match.

Should I loop over each array and do "if" checks to see if the account and percent already exist, then add up amount, else leave it as it is?

Is there a php function for this?

I have been looking into array_unique but I'm not quite sure how to do it like that.

As always, any help is appreciated!

Comment: No, there is no function for this. PHP is a toolbox with some basic hammers, screwdrivers, and occasional swiss army knife. It will never have `the_function_that_does_some_complex_operation_that_only_one_person_in_the_universe_needs()`. so get busy with [foreach()](http://php.net/foreach) and [if()](http://php.net/if)

Comment: The simple way I could suggest you that, before adding new array value to your existing array loop over each index, if value is found just update with new amount and if not then add it to that array. I think your are also thinking same manner to deal this problem.

Comment: @maytham, I need to check if both account and percent are already existing. If they match than add the amount to the previous amount. In the example it would mean the last 2 arrays are counted like this: Account = 705300, percent = 21, amount = 66.12 (8.26 + 57.86)

Comment: If there are 5 account AND percent the same I need to add up the amount of the 5 matching arrays

Comment: I already have this:
foreach ($logicalarray as $array){ if(in_array($array['account'], $array) && in_array($array['percent'], $array)){
    $amount += $array['amount'];
    $newarray = array('account' => $array['account'], 'percent' => $array['percent'], 'amount' => $amount); 
   }
  }
  print_r($newarray);

But it just adds up every amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this. It will generate a nested structure that seems like it would probably be easier to work with.

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $grouped[$item['account']][$item['percent']] += $item['amount'];
}
```

If you need to put them back into the original format, just do basically the opposite operation

```
foreach ($grouped as $account => $percents) {
    foreach ($percents as $percent => $amount) {
        $new_array[] = array(
            'account' => $account, 'percent' => $percent, 'amount' => $amount);
    }
}
```